# Failed to write file to disk in WordPress While uploading media files

Tags: wordpress, permissions, upload

I am getting following error while uploading media in WordPress on AWS server.

```
"Failed to write file to disk"
```

I have changed folder permission by using the following command:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
```

Still, it is not working.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.9G  417M  7.5G   6% /run
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  8.0G  3.7M 100% /
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: do you have memory enought in your server hdd?

Comment: @David, I updated my question, please see it.

Comment: I see your main directory `/` is full 8.0 Gb used of 8.0 Gb. I don't know how is it deployed but try assigning more data there

Comment: @David, So what should I do now?

Comment: go to your server's admin page and search for an option to change disc sizes or something like that, I can't help you there you have to know what are you paid for, I don't even know if you are using a local server or by a provider

Comment: @David, Thanks it helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out this issue with the help `@David`. As He told, there was the memory issue on the server side.

As I checked the disk was full.

```
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  8.0G  3.7M 100% /
```

The main directory `/` was full `8.0 GB` used of `8.0 GB`.

Solution:

```
Just Upgrade your disk size.
```

Answer (score 1):

depending on your webserver/php configuration you may end up with folder ownership and PHP process running via different users/groups.

Start with giving

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
```

or even

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/wp-content
```

But it it works, but 755 doesn't - that's a sign of your system misconfiguration. That may be fine for development, but should never be used in production.

Comment: I used this command but not working sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/wp-content

Comment: In that case check your php uploads temp folder.

It's upload_tmp_dir option in php.ini or make a php file to get it

<?php 
var_dump( ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') ); 
var_dump( sys_get_temp_dir() );